# Sequelize: How to use AND operator in WHERE on the same column?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, and-operator

I have this query:

```
model.findAndCountAll({
  attributes: ['FirstName', 'LastName'],
  include: [{
    model: models['hobbies'],
    as: 'Hobbies',
    attributes: ['ID', 'Name'],
    where: {
      [Sequelize.Op.and]: [
        { 'ID': 1 },
        { 'ID': 2 }
      ]
    }
  }]
})
```

I am trying to get an employee with the two hobbies specified in the query though it returns 0 rows. AND operator doesn't seem to work when applied to the same column. Is there a way to handle this kind of query?

Employee table data:

```
 EmployeeID | FirstName | LastName | HobbyID
------------+-----------+----------+----------
          1 | John      | Doe      | 1
          1 | John      | Doe      | 1
          2 | Jane      | Doe      | 1
```

Employee table association:

```
model.hasMany(models['Hobbies'], { as: 'Hobbies', foreignKey: 'EmployeeID', targetKey: 'EmployeeID' });
```

Output:

```
{
  count: 0,
  rows: []
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  FirstName: "John",
  LastName: "Doe",
  Hobbies: [
    { Name: "Sports - Basketball" },
    { Name: "Sports - Volleyball" }
  ]
}
```

And it should always return employees with both of the hobbies specified.

Comment: What is the actual output and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
model.findAndCountAll({
  attributes: ['FirstName', 'LastName'],
  include: [{
    model: models['hobbies'],
    as: 'Hobbies',
    attributes: ['ID', 'Name'],
    where: {
        ID: [1,2]
      ]
    }
  }]
})
```